# How to access ShippingAddress PostalCode in ARInvoiceEntry graph override

Tags: acumatica

I am extending `ARInvoiceEntry` graph and adding an even handler for `RowPersisting`, but the only data I see in the invoice is `ShipAddressID`:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
  public class ARInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
  {
    protected void ARInvoice_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e, PXRowPersisting InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
      var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
      if (row != null)
      {
        // ???
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do I need to use that ShipAddressID and run a query? If the address is an override, query wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the current `ARShippingAddress` record from the base graph `Shipping_Address` dataview.

```
public void ARInvoice_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
  ARInvoice invoice = e.Row as ARInvoice;
  ARShippingAddress shipAddress = Base.Shipping_Address.Select();

  if (invoice != null && shipAddress != null)
  {
    throw new PXException("Address Line 1: " + shipAddress.AddressLine1 + Environment.NewLine +
                          "Address Line 2: " + shipAddress.AddressLine2 + Environment.NewLine +
                          "Address Line 3: " + shipAddress.AddressLine3 + Environment.NewLine);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: For your specific requirement, use field ARShippingAddress.PostalCode instead of the address line fields shown in my answer example.